# How to provide a Service object to OWIN and access from Api controller

Tags: asp.net-web-api, owin, unity-container, katana, asp.net-apicontroller

I have a self-hosted OWIN App and I want to provide a Service (MyService) object when the WebApp is started and the use it from the Api Controllers.

The Service object is instantiated just before I start up the OWIN app and I need to have access to this object from an Api Controller.

This is how I manually start up the self-host WebAPI from my main.cs class:

```cs
var webApi = new StartWebApi();
var stopEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
webApi.Start(myService, stopEvent);
```

I pass MyService instance to the controller via Unity container but it is null when the constructor of the WebApi controller is called.

the OWIN start method (using Action to pass the instance of MyService):

```cs
public class StartWebApi
{
    public void Start(IMyService myService, WaitHandle stopEvent)
    {
        if (stopEvent == null) { return; }

        const string BaseAddress = "http://*:9123/";
        using (WebApp.Start(
            BaseAddress, 
            (appBuilder) =>
                {
                    new Startup(myService).Configuration(appBuilder);           
                }))
            {
                stopEvent.WaitOne();
            }
    }
}
```

the StartUp class:

```cs
public sealed class Startup
{
    private readonly IMyService myService;

    public Startup(IMyService myService)
    {
        this.myService = myService;
    }

    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
    {
        var configuration = new HttpConfiguration();
        var container = new UnityContainer();

        this.ConfigureDependencies(container);
        configuration.DependencyResolver = new UnityDependencyResolver(container);

        appBuilder.UseWebApi(configuration);            
    }

    private void ConfigureDependencies(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        // Am I missing something here to instruct Unity to resolve?
        container.RegisterInstance<IMyService>(this.myService);
    }
}
```

and the controller:

```cs
public class MyController : ApiController
{
    private readonly IMyService myService;

    public MyController(IMyService myService)
    {
        this.myService= myService;
    }

    public IHttpActionResult RunService(string serviceName)
    {
        // ERROR, myService is null
        myService.Run(serviceName);
       return this.Ok(); 
    }
}
```

So far what I can see is that the Controller constructor is hit but variable myService is null :(

What am I doing wrong? Is the Unity RegisterInstance not correct?

Comment: Provide a [mcve] to better explain what it is you are tryin to achieve.

Comment: Please share your StartUp.cs and point out the service you need to access in the controllers

Comment: @MarcusH Added the code, I hope it clear now what I want to achieve. Basically I need in a Controller access to an object instance created before the WebAPI was started.

Comment: @Nkosi provided

Comment: @AgustinBerbegall are you familiar with Dependency Inversion? Assign a `IDependencyResolver` derived implementation to the `HttpConfiguration..DependencyResolver` as a service provider and register your service with it. When the controllers are created the dependency will be initialized if not singleton and injected into the dependent controller. Review the following [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/dependency-injection)

Comment: @Nkosi yes I'm a bit familiar, but I wanted to avoid adding the Unity to this project... and still the problem is that I don't have control on how the service class is instantiated, I will only have access to the object right before I start up the WebAPI, I'm not sure if it will work with Unity and I thought there could be another way provided by OWIN, something like [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.owin.hosting.services.serviceprovider.addinstance(v=vs.113).aspx), I don't know.

Comment: I should not instruct Unity to create an instance of MyService, as it already exists and I can only use that instance. The instance is create by another module and it simply provides that to the main class object.

Comment: then create your instance and register it as a singleton so that the same instance is provided every time when called.

Comment: What do you mean by that? I cannot create an instance of MyService, it's been created by another module (I'm sorry if my code confused you)

Comment: @Nkosi I'm now having a look to the dependency injection fundamentals [link](http://jakeydocs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fundamentals/dependency-injection.html) and see if it can help me

Comment: @AgustinBerbegall that link you provided in your last comment is for Asp.Net Core The one I provided earlier is for web api 2 which I beleive is the version you are using.

Comment: @Nkosi after I added and configured the Unity contained, it worked fine... the above code worked for me. Thank you.

Comment: @AgustinBerbegall yes I was watching to see what you did and it improves as you went along.I was trying to figure out why you were getting issues as everything looked Ok when I reviewed the code..